# How to configure spring loaded in properties files

Tags: spring-boot, spring-loaded

I was doing hot deployment using spring loaded, with setup command line arguments it is working fine. But I want to do it using properties file, so how can I configure spring loaded using properties file?

Comment: run a file watcher daemon and reload!

Comment: create an application.properties file in your classpath, then Spring will automatically pick up the file. (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)